# Different permission between directory and file with 'umask'

Tags: permissions, umask

Why is umask setting a different permission for a directory and file I have created
Consider:

```
[user@server1 ~]$ umask
0770
[user@server1 ~]$ mkdir TEST2; touch TEST2.txt;
[user@server1 ~]$ ls -l
d------rwx 2 user group_name 4096 Mar  5 05:16 TEST2
-------rw- 1 user group_name    0 Mar  5 05:16 TEST2.txt
```

Now shouldn't the file `TEST2.txt` have the permission `007` as `umask` is set to `0770`?

Comment: See [How does gcc handle file permissions?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66503/66623#66623)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

umask doesn't enforce rights, it forbids them. Have a look at strace:

```
file:
open("newfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
directory:
mkdir("newdir", 0777)                   = 0
```

touch doesn't ask for execution rights for a file (which wouldn't make sense).

Comment: Thanks Hauke for the explanation! I read [here](http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSUserG/_default_perms_new_file.html) and in some other places that `umask` will never set the 'x' permission expect when creating a directory or compiling a program to create an executable binary.

Comment: So when we say that umask forbids rights, it means that the process creating the file might try to give the file more permissions that umask would allow. So umask will then ensure that the illegal permissions are "masked-out"? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @KentPawar A compiler will usually ask for the execute right for a file. Indeed, as the name says: umask masks rights out.

Comment: Why can't `umask` set a file to be `775` by default? Is it dangerous? I can do it manually, why does it limit me here?

Answer (score 2):

The `umask` value is permissions to *deny*, taken off whatever permissions would be given by default. A directory requires search permission, so unless overriden its permissions are 0777 (rwxrwxrwx), with the typical umask of 0002 it leaves 0775 (rwxrwxr-x). For an executable the same (x means execute here); for a regular file default permissions are no execute, rw-rw-rw- (0666), with the above umask 0664 (rwxrwxr--).

Answer (score 0):

umask is a value that is basically the complement of the default permission value. So, if umask shows 002, that means the default permission is 775. Other examples for better understanding include umask=000 => perms=777 or umask=777 => perms=000 .

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But I could not get why the 'x' permission was taken away automatically..