# setting umask for directories and files

Tags: shell, umask

Is it possible to create an umask , which will result in newly created files and directorties to have the same access rights ? e.g both of them to have for example

```
rwxrwrw
```

Directories starts with 777 - umask , and files with 666 - umask , but is it possible to create such an umask?

Comment: Any reason you want a non executable directory?

Comment: it is just an example , to demonstrate that both files and directories should have same rights

Comment: possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66910/why-is-umask-setting-a-different-permission-for-a-directory-and-file-i-have-crea

Comment: On Linux, you can kind of get this by using filesystems that don't have any concept of permissions (such as vfat) and using the `umask=` option when mounting them to give them simulated permissions. Of course, this is filesystem-wide and will apply to all users who can access the filesystem, regardless of their own umasks and any use of the chmod command.

Answer (score 1):

No - that would be doable only if the applications *requested* the same permissions for both directories and files.  But `fopen` uses `0666` for files, and direct `open` calls commonly use the same permissions, while directories require execute privilege to be useful, so they are usually requested with `0777` (or `0755`, depending on the application).